# What is the browser/javascript API used for "parallel tracking"?

Tags: javascript, browser

Few years ago, the concept of "parallel tracking" came to life. I remember reading about it and how it works - the idea is instead of tracking a click by linking to the tracking website and then the tracking site redirecs to the destination, the browser will load both the destination and the tracking URL at the same time (obviously showing only the destination page) - improving performance of page load.

However, I can't easily find what is the browser mechanism to do so. I thought maybe folks here can help? This is NOT XHR, as it will get canceled once the new page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon):

> This method addresses the needs of analytics and diagnostics code that
>   typically attempts to send data to a web server prior to the unloading
>   of the document. Sending the data any sooner may result in a missed
>   opportunity to gather data. However, ensuring that the data has been
>   sent during the unloading of a document is something that has
>   traditionally been difficult for developers, because user agents
>   typically ignore asynchronous XMLHttpRequests made in an unload
>   handler.
>
> To solve this problem, analytics and diagnostics code have
>   historically made a synchronous XMLHttpRequest call in an unload or
>   beforeunload event handler to submit the data. The synchronous
>   XMLHttpRequest blocks the process of unloading the document, which in
>   turn causes the next navigation appear to be slower. There is nothing
>   the next page can do to avoid this perception of poor page load
>   performance, and the result is that the user perceives that the new
>   web page is slow to load, even though the true issue is with the
>   previous page.
>
> There are other workaround techniques which have been used to ensure
>   that this kind of data is submitted. One such technique is to delay
>   the unload in order to submit data by creating an  element and
>   setting its src attribute within the unload handler. As most user
>   agents will delay the unload to complete the pending image load, data
>   can be submitted during the unload. Another technique is to create a
>   no-op loop for several seconds within the unload handler to delay the
>   unload and submit data to a server.
>
> Not only do these techniques represent poor coding patterns, some of
>   them are unreliable and all of them result in the perception of poor
>   page load performance for the next navigation.
>
> This is where sendBeacon() comes in. By using the sendBeacon() method,
>   the data is transmitted asynchronously to the web server when the User
>   Agent has an opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or
>   affecting the performance of the next navigation. This solves all of
>   the problems with submission of analytics data: the data is sent
>   reliably, it's sent asynchronously, and it doesn't impact the loading
>   of the next page. In addition, the code is actually simpler to write
>   than any of these other techniques!

Comment: Thank you, Bergi!